# Наследование коллекций

Tags: java, наследование, коллекции

В моей программе реализован абстрактный класс `Users` от  которого наследуются классы `Worker` и `Customer`. Я хочу создать списки пользователей отдельно для `Worker` и `Customer`. У этих списков довольно похожий функционал. **Вопрос:** Могу ли я как то реализовать методы в абстрактном классе чтобы я мог применить их на все ArrayList'ы в моей программе или для каждого списка нужно реализовывать методы отдельно?
 Про наследование коллекций не смог найти понятной инфы. Я пытался использовать Raw - тип и дженерики, но тогда эти методы не работают для `Worker` и `Customer` списков. Пример моего использования находится после кода.

Код:

```
package BankCode;

public abstract class User {
    private String name, surname, lastname;
    private String login, password;
public User(String name, String surname, String lastname, String login, String password){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}

public abstract void Im();
}

package BankCode;

public class Customer extends User {

    private boolean count, card;

    public Customer(String name, String surname, String lastname, String login, String password){
        super(name, surname, lastname, login, password);
    }

    public void PutMoneyOnAcc(){}

    public void WithdrawFromCard(){}

    public void TransferCardAcc(){}

    public void Im(){
        System.out.print("Я посетитель");
    }
}

package BankCode;

public class Worker extends User {

    public Worker(String name, String surname, String lastname, String login, String password){
        super(name, surname, lastname, login, password);
    }

    public void OpenAccount(){}

    public void CreateCard(){}

    public void CloseCount(){}

    public void CreateAccount(){}

    public void Im(){
        System.out.print("Я рабочий");
    }
}
```

Пример использования дженериков:

```
package BankCode;

import java.util.List;

abstract class UserList {

private boolean loginCheck(String login, List<?> b){
    boolean availability = true;
    for (Object u : b){
        if (login.equals(u.getLogin())) availability = !availability;
    }
    return availability;
}

boolean addUser(User a, List<?> b){
    boolean adding = true;
    if (loginCheck(a.getLogin(), b))b.add(a);
    else adding = false;
    return adding;
    }
}
```

В этом примере возникает ошибка когда я пытаюсь обратиться к методу `a.getLogin`. А при использовании Raw - типа выдаёт ошибку когда я пытаюсь передать `ArrayList<Worker>` в метод `addUser`.

Comment: `loginCheck(String login, List<? extends User> b)` и `addUser(User a, List<? extends User> b)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код избыточный. Все переменные типа boolean фактически лишние. 
Ваш метод loginCheck имеет модификатор доступа private , это значит, что к нему может обратиться исключительно метод addUser. Поскольку тип возвращаемого значения у двух методах boolean , то вполне логично если метод addUser после проверки условия и обращения к методу loginCheck будет возвращать значение, которое вернул метод loginCheck (инче смысла в возвращаемом значении метода loginCheck  нет!).
Посему Ваша проблема решается примерно так:

```
import java.util.List;

abstract class UserList<T extends User> {

    private boolean loginCheck(final String login, final List<T> b) {
        return b.stream().noneMatch(t -> login.equals(t.getLogin()));
    }

    boolean addUser(final T t, final List<T> b) {
        return loginCheck(t.getLogin(), b) ? b.add(t) : false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю наследоваться от коллекций нормальная практика, вот пример `org.jsoup.select.Elements` реализует это таким образом

1. Содержит в себе приватный список(!).

   ```
   public class Elements implements List<Element>, Cloneable {
       private List<Element> contents;
   ...
   }
   ```
2. Конструкторы, которые предоставляю исчерпывающий функционал инициализации

   ```
   public Elements() {
       this.contents = new ArrayList();
   }

   public Elements(int initialCapacity) {
       this.contents = new ArrayList(initialCapacity);
   }

   public Elements(Collection<Element> elements) {
       this.contents = new ArrayList(elements);
   }

   public Elements(List<Element> elements) {
       this.contents = elements;
   }

   public Elements(Element... elements) {
       this(Arrays.asList(elements));
   }
   ```
3. Внутренний функционал использует итератор.

   ```
   public Elements addClass(String className) {
       Iterator i$ = this.contents.iterator();

       while(i$.hasNext()) {
           Element element = (Element)i$.next();
           element.addClass(className);
       }

       return this;
   }

   public Elements removeClass(String className) {
       Iterator i$ = this.contents.iterator();

       while(i$.hasNext()) {
           Element element = (Element)i$.next();
           element.removeClass(className);
       }

       return this;
   }
   ```
4. Специальные методы доступа.

   ```
   public Element first() {
       return this.contents.isEmpty() ? null : (Element)this.contents.get(0);
   }

   public Element last() {
       return this.contents.isEmpty() ? null : (Element)this.contents.get(this.contents.size() - 1);
   }
   ```
5. Реализацию интерфейса `List`, делегируем нашему приватному полю.

   ```
   public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
       return this.contents.toArray(a);
   }

   public boolean add(Element element) {
       return this.contents.add(element);
   }

   public boolean remove(Object o) {
       return this.contents.remove(o);
   }
   ```